# Grub says "Loading Stage 2"

Tags: grub, cd-rom

I'm trying to make a bootable CD-rom. The CD is supposed to use grub to boot. I found a download of stage2_eltorito (this is the file that is used to create a bootable grub disk) and I burned it onto the disk. I rebooted from the disc and it just says "Loading Stage2 ...." and it hangs. I can't figure out my mistake.

So I tried putting the files stage1 and stage2 on a CD and it wrote "GRUB _" to the screen and then hung. Does anyone think I am better of putting Stage1 and Stage2 onto the CD, than using the Stage2_eltorito which is actually made for creating grub CDs?

I also tried to put the file "initrd" onto the disk with stage2_eltorito. But when I boot from the CD it says "Loading Stage2 " with some hundred dots after that! Does anyone know the cause of all these weird things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After googeling a little, I found [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=197514).
In the article the author explains that when stage 1 runs it writes the word "GRUB " like that with a space after it in the top left corner on the screen. When stage two runs it adds the words "Loading Stage 2." So if stage 1 runs and for some reason stage 2 fails to run after that you will end up with the word "GRUB" and a space in your top left corner. He also explains that if stage 1 runs and for some reason it calls itself to run after it instead of calling stage 2 and this continues in an infinite loop, you will end up with a screen saying "GRUB GRUB GRUB GRUB" all over the screen! Now, in the other case where I used the stage2_eltorito this whole thing does not apply. There, I made a different mistake. When using ImgBurn to create your bootable disc you have to check off the box where it says "Patch Boot information Table". When I did that it worked. So, yes I do think I am better off using stage2_eltorito, but I have to click on "Patch Boot Information Table".